# Incomplete type until C++17?

Tags: c++, c++11, variadic-templates, c++17, template-specialization

I thought the code below was valid C++11, but GCC (g++ (GCC) 8.0.0 20170528) rejects it; reporting that the variable `f` has an incomplete type. It does though compile with the `-std=c++17` flag. Can anyone tell me why?

```
#include <type_traits>

template <class> struct Foo;

template <
  template <template <class ...> class> class MM,
  template <class...> class M
>
struct Foo<MM<M>> {};

template <template <class ...> class, class...>
struct Bar { };

Foo<Bar<std::add_pointer>> f;
```

Comment: Possibly because `std::add_pointer` is a `template<class> class`, not a `template<class...> class`?

Comment: No, it's the same with a `template <class...> class>` such as `std::common_type`.

Comment: @T.C. [temp.arg.template]/3 talks about what happens when `P`'s _template-parameter-list_ contains a template parameter pack, but here it's `A`'s _template-parameter-list_ that contains the extra template parameter pack.  I think by a strict reading, this is ill-formed C++11.

Comment: @aschepler Oh right, I misread OP's example. Yes, you're right, this is ill-formed pre-DR150.